# Send an Image with MSMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, msmessage, msmessagetemplatelayout

I'm finishing the iMessage Extension but I've a little problem, I want to send a simple Image using MSMessage.
Now I Use this Code :

```
 MSMessage *message = [[MSMessage alloc] init];  
    MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc]init];  

    [layout setImage:myImage];  
     message.layout = layout;  

    [savedConversation insertMessage:message completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {  

    }];
```

But I don't want to use the MSMessateTemplateLayout like this:
[Standard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W935n.png)

I want only send a simple Image.
How can I do this?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I find the solution :

```
MSMessage *message = [[MSMessage alloc] init];

MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc]init];

NSString *stringURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),@"temp.jpg"];


NSURL *urlImage = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:stringURl];


NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self imageWithView:self.myViewBgImageConLogoDaSalvare], 0.0);
        [dataImage writeToURL:urlImage atomically:true];

[savedConversation insertAttachment:urlImage withAlternateFilename:nil completionHandler:^(NSError * error) {

        }];
```

Comment: For more, 1. https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-10-imessages-sdk-creating-an-imessages-extension                                                            2. https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/interactive-messages-in-ios-10-4cea542fbd9a#.bi7m5xd1q